# R to R communication

Tags: r, sockets, rpc

I use [RExcel](http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download.html) on uni processor virtual Windows XP box on Linux host. Some calculations I do take long time, and I delegate them to host, which can do them in parallel.

The way I do this is by automated creation of R scripts, that are simply executed by `Rscript` on host.

I wonder, if there is a possibility to have a network-based communication between R sessions? I know about the [RServe package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rserve/index.html), but I can't find an R client (although the documentation states, that the simple R client is included). It also states, that there are better ways for R-to-R communication, but fails to mention them...

I plan to communicate between Windows 32-bit and Linux 64-bit versions of R, both with the same version number. If it helps, I can run 32-bit version of R on the Linux host too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the RExcel side of things, but I have used the parallel package (and the snow package (no relation) loaded by parallel) to connect parallel instances of R running on a Linux based supercomputer to the instance of R running on my Windows based computer.  This meant that I could type a command on the Windows computer and it was broken up into pieces, sent to the parallel instances on the supercomputer for processing, then collected the results back to the windows computer.  However, this resulted in a lot of communication overhead which meant that some tests actually ran slower by being parallelized (would have been quicker to transfer everything to the supercomputer, run R parallel there, then transfer the results back).

Look through the documentation of the parallel and snow packages for details.

Comment: I think that this is enough to me. Somehow I missed the keyword "parallel" in my searches (and focused on the "networking" part). Now I see the page http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html which has everything I need. I hope it wouldn't be too difficult to setup something from there.